# Reading and Writing to Firebase RT not update the UI or Backend

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I've been trying to get a registered user to rate an item and then display it on the UI, but neither of this works. When I click on the button send the feedback, it doesn't update. Can anyone help please suggesting with a simpler approach.

This is the code on my Feedback activity for the button send feedback or rating.

```
   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    WeekMenu weekMenu = (WeekMenu) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("WeekMenu");
    mSeekBar = findViewById(R.id.feedbackActivity_seekbar);
    mButtonSend = findViewById(R.id.feedbackActivity_btnSend);
    mSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        float seekBarValue = 0;

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            seekBarValue = ((float) progress / 10.0f);
            mTextViewRating.setText("" + seekBarValue);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            seekBarValue = ((float) (seekBar.getProgress() / 10.0f));
            mWeekMenu.setRating(String.valueOf(Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf((seekBar.getProgress() / 10.0f)))));
            mTextViewRating.setText("" + seekBarValue);
        }
    });
    mTextViewRating.setText(mWeekMenu.getRating());

        mButtonSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            mWeekMenu.setRating(mTextViewRating.getText().toString());

            DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference = AppRepository.mDatabaseReference;
            if (weekMenu.getId() == null) {
                mDatabaseReference.push().setValue(weekMenu)
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Object o) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(FeedbackActivity.this, 
                                                           WeekMenuActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra("WeekMenu", weekMenu);
                                setResult(RESULT_OK);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        })
                        .addOnFailureListener(e -> e.printStackTrace());
            } else {
                mDatabaseReference.child(weekMenu.getId()).setValue(weekMenu)
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Object o) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(FeedbackActivity.this, 
WeekMenuActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra("WeekMenu", weekMenu);
                                setResult(RESULT_OK);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        })
                        .addOnFailureListener(e -> e.printStackTrace());
            }
        }
    });
```

This is how I have tried to get the rating in the WeekMenuActivity in the onCreate() method. I'm not sure how it should look like. My problem is write or read to/from the database.

```
  private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
private DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;
private ChildEventListener mChildEventListener;
private ArrayList<WeekMenu> mWeekMenuArrayList = new ArrayList();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_week_menu);

    AppRepository.openFBReference("WeekMenu", (WeekMenuActivity) this);
    mFirebaseDatabase = AppRepository.mFirebaseDatabase;
    mDatabaseReference =mFirebaseDatabase.getReference();
    mDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("WeekMenu");

    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewMenu);
    final WeekMenuAdapter adapter = new WeekMenuAdapter(mWeekMenuArrayList, this);

    WeekMenu menuWithRating = (WeekMenu) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("WeekMenu");

    if (menuWithRating != null) {
        menuWithRating.getRating();
        mDatabaseReference.push().setValue(menuWithRating);
    }
}
```

The code in the adapter class is as below:

```
 public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    public TextView txtViewName, txtViewDescription, txtViewRating;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        txtViewName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_week_day);
        txtViewDescription = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_dishes_description);
        txtViewRating = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_rates);
       
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void bind(WeekMenu weekMenu) {
        txtViewName.setText(weekMenu.getName());
        txtViewDescription.setText(weekMenu.getDescription());
        if (weekMenu.getRating() != null && !weekMenu.getRating().isEmpty()) {
            txtViewRating.setText(weekMenu.getRating());
        }
    }
```

Comment: We can't see the values of the variables you're using here. And you're not checking setValue for errors, so something could be going wrong.  Please edit your question to explain in more detail exactly what this code should do, and add code to check for errors.

Comment: I have updated with all the code that I have. I'm not sure how exactly it is being done to write the rating and display it on the calling activity.